# Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error when I try to run a basic script in Google Sheet's script editor:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")Dismiss
```

Script:

```
function autoResponder(e){
var user = {name: e.namedValues['Name'][0], email: e.namedValues['Email'][0]};
var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> Test </h2><br />' +
        '<p> Greetings Earthling </p>' +
    '</body>'  

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    email,         // recipient
    'test GmailApp',                 // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: html                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 

}
```

This is the complete code.
I used following link to get auto emails when someone submits a new form.
https://codingislove.com/auto-responding-google-form-2-lines-code/#comment-50377
Then I tried to change it to HTML email. 
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Do you have any idea why this may be happening?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: console.log(e) on first line of function

Comment: The error means that `e` is `undefined`.

Comment: How you are calling function `autoResponder ` as `e` seems to be undefined

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see the changes. 
That is the complete code, I took this script from the link above. It worked, then it stops working when I tried to do some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any value when you call `autoResponder()`.

Unless you show us that part of your code, we can only guess why.
@Ashish suggested putting  `console.log(e)` as the first line inside your function, but we already know what that will show: `undefined`  so you need to trace back a little earlier in your code.